# Is there a substitute for Java's new() in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, initialization, new-operator

I am trying to create a simple poker game in C and am having difficulty with getting my card structures inside of an array using a loop so that I do not have to individually create each card object and then put them inside of the array manually one by one. I am more familiar with Java and know that I could use the "new className(class parameters)" method for inputting new objects inside of an array without naming and initializing them one by one. This is essentially what I would be doing in Java, and am wondering if there is a way to do this using C.

```java
    for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++){
        table_deck.deck[i] = new card("diamonds", i);
    }
```

[screenshot of my C attempt thus far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8tkC.png)

I tried doing the attached photo but will not pass compilation. I was hoping that there is some way for me to do this without manually initializing 52 cards individually and them inserting them inside of my array 52 individually.

Comment: You should post your code as *text* in a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not as a screenshot.

Comment: Asking questions here is not the way to learn the basics of a programming language. Too broad.

Comment: A big difference between Java and C is that Java emphasizes storing objects in the heap (and garbage collecting them), while C (and C++ if you go there) emphasizes putting structs and objects on the stack when possible, so they are cleaned up when leaving a function scope (because heap management is manual). Copying versus shuffling handles around is a different mindset.

Comment: If you want to learn C, then forget java. Do not apply a java mindset when coding in C. It's going to be a lose-lose situation.

Comment: `14` looks ***bad** magic*. `playerDeck[2]`?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This OP-linked code seems to want to assign a struct value to an array element:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    table_deck.deck[i] = struct card {"diamonds", i};
}
```

The above code isn't legal in C, but you could use a *compound literal* to accomplish this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    table_deck.deck[i] = (struct card){"diamonds", i};
}
```

A compound literal creates an unnamed object, and if it occurs outside of any function that object has static storage duration. Otherwise the unnamed object has automatic storage duration which ends when the block in which the compound literal occurs is exited.

In general you have to be careful with the lifetimes of objects created through compound literals. The compound literals in the above code occur in a `for` loop body, and their storage is restricted to that block. The assignment `table_deck.deck[i] = (struct card){"diamonds", i};` copies the contents of the unnamed structs into the indexed structs `table_deck.deck[i]`.

Using a compound literal here is just a convenience. Another way to accomplish the same thing would be to simply assign directly to the relevant fields. You could modify the `suit` field of the `card` struct to accept a pointer to `char`, or perhaps better a pointer to `const char`. Then a string literal (which decays to a pointer to `char` in static memory) can be assigned to the pointer:

```
struct card {
    const char *suit;
    int value;
};

/* ... */
int main(void) {
    /* ... */
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        table_deck.deck[i].suit = "diamonds";
        table_deck.deck[i].value = i;
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Or you could leave the `card` struct as it is and copy characters into the `suit` field:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct card {
    char suit[9];
    int value;
};

/* ... */
int main(void) {
    /* ... */
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        strcpy(table_deck.deck[i].suit, "diamonds");
        table_deck.deck[i].value = i;
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

If you elect to try a solution like this you must be certain that any strings you attempt to copy into a `suit` field will fit (including the `\0` terminator). You might want to use `strncpy` instead, but this brings its own issues since `strncpy` can leave its target arrays without null termination.

Answer (score 0):

C does not have classes the way Java does. The closest substitute is a `struct` that can store members. What Java `new` does is allocates the memory for a new instance of a class. The closest equivalent in C would be either using `malloc()` and assigning the fields:

```
struct card {
    char suit[9];
    int value;
};
struct card *my_card = malloc(sizeof(struct card));
my_card->name = "diamonds";
my_card->number = 7;
free(my_card);
```

Or just declaring/using a stack variable:

```
struct card my_card = {"diamonds", 7};
```

If you like the idea of passing parameters to a function:

```
struct card card_init(char *suit, int value) {
    struct card tmp;
    strcpy(tmp, suit);
    card.value = value;
    return tmp;
}
```

Upon looking at the image, the syntax you are looking for is called a compound literal:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++){
    table_deck.deck[i] = (struct card){"diamonds", i};
}
```